# Rewriting a txt file in python, creating new lines where there is a certain string

Tags: python, text-processing

I have converted a PDF bank statement to a txt file. Here is a snippet of the .txt file:

```
15 Apr 20DDOPEN 100.00DDBENNON WATER SRVCS29.00DDBG BUSINESS106.00BPC BOB PETROL MINISTRY78.03BPC BARBARA STREAMING DATA30.50CRPAYPAL Z4J22FR450.00CRPAYNAL AAWDL4Z4J22222KHMG30.0019,028.4917 Apr 20CRCASH IN AT HSBC BANK
```

What is the easiest way of re-writing the text file in python to create a new line at certain points. i.e. after a number ‘xx.xx’ there in a new date such as ‘xx APR’

For example the text to become:

```
15 Apr 20DDOPEN 100.00
BENNON WATER SRVCS29.00
DDBG BUSINESS106.00...(etc)
```

I am just trying to make a PDF more readable and useful when working amongst my other files.

If you know of another PDF to txt python converter which works better, I would also be interested.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step would be getting the text file into Python

```
with open(“file.txt”) as file:  
    data = file.read()
```

This next part, initially, I thought you wouldn't be able to do, but in your example, each part contains a number XX.XX The important thing to notice here is that there is a '.' in each number.

Using Python's string find command, you can iteratively look for that '.' and add a newline character two characters later. You can change my indices below to remove the DD as well if you want.

```
index = 0
while(index != -1):
    index = data.find('.', index)
    if index != -1:
        data = data[:index+3] + '\n' + data[index+3:]
```

Then you need to write the new data back to the file.

```
file = open('ValidEmails.txt','w')
file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given input the following should work:

```
import re

counter = 0
l = "15 Apr 20DDOPEN 100.00DDBENNON WATER SRVCS29.00DDBG BUSINESS106.00BPC BOB PETROL MINISTRY78.03BPC BARBARA STREAMING DATA30.50CRPAYPAL Z4J22FR450.00CRPAYNAL AAWDL4Z4J22222KHMG30.0019,028.4917 Apr 20CRCASH IN AT HSBC BANK"

nums = re.finditer("[\d]+[\.][\d]+", l)
for elem in nums:
    idx = elem.span()[1] + counter
    l = l[:idx] + '\n' + l[idx:]
    counter += 1
print(l)
```

The output is:

```
15 Apr 20DDOPEN 100.00
DDBENNON WATER SRVCS29.00
DDBG BUSINESS106.00
BPC BOB PETROL MINISTRY78.03
BPC BARBARA STREAMING DATA30.50
CRPAYPAL Z4J22FR450.00
CRPAYNAL AAWDL4Z4J22222KHMG30.0019
,028.4917
 Apr 20CRCASH IN AT HSBC BANK
```

Then you should easily able to write line by line to a file.